# Does Numbers on the iPad pro allow you to sketch with the Apple Pencil?

Tags: ipad, numbers

Using Apple Numbers a lot on my iPad iOS 9.2.1

Due to the limited availability, I haven't seen anyone sporting an Apple Pencil with an iPad Pro. Stores in my area have the iPad Pro but no Pencil.

Does Numbers on the iPad pro allow you to sketch with the Apple Pencil? What happens when you sketch on the Numbers canvas? Can you freehand a simple sketch?

Comment: What do you mean by "canvas"?

Comment: The white background that you put the tables on, move them around add text on it and so on. (or a more general approach, can you draw anywhere in numbers, anywhere at all?)

Comment: No it's just a workspace not a canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer **No**

The background that tables, graphs, images etc. rest above is just a workspace.

It's not a canvas. (Just to be complete I did try it with my Pencil in my iPad Pro)

Comment: How are shapes drawn? When you select + and then Shapes (colored boxes, lines, etc) and select a Line... If you click to create it it works just as before you have to drag the ends?

Comment: Yes it doesn't change with the Pencil

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw in numbers with an Apple Pencil but your Apple Pencil will work the same way you use your finger.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  This question already has an accepted answer and your answer just repeats, essentially, that answer without providing additional, necessary, info.  Please see [answer] for tips on how to write a good answer.  - From Review